# Unhandled Exception: DioError PONSE]: Http status error [500]

Tags: android, post, flutter, dart, dio

I made FormData use the dio package to upload images to the database, but my compilation was running "flutter run", an error appeared.

After I see the error that appears is a problem with the Http status error [500].

```dart
Dio dio = new Dio();
dio.options.headers = {
        'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      };

FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
          'name': image_name,
          'path': add_path + _uniq[0],
          'uuid': _uuid,
          'content_type': add_file + image_type,
          'file': _image[0],
          'record': null
       });

Map<String, dynamic> token_send = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        token_send = {'token': userGlobal['token']};
        response_data = await dio.post(
            host + apiVersion + "/formuploads/uploadformattachment",
            data: formData,
            queryParameters: token_send
        );
```

Then I run it by "flutter run". Then an error appears in the terminal as follows:

```
E/flutter ( 2970): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: DioError [DioErrorType.RESPONSE]: Http status error [500]
E/flutter ( 2970): #0      DioMixin._dispatchRequest (package:dio/src/dio.dart:943:7)
E/flutter ( 2970): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 2970): #1      DioMixin._request._interceptorWrapper.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous 
closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:dio/src/dio.dart:828:37)
E/flutter ( 2970): #2      DioMixin.checkIfNeedEnqueue (package:dio/src/dio.dart:1099:22)       
E/flutter ( 2970): #3      DioMixin._request._interceptorWrapper.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous 
closure> (package:dio/src/dio.dart:825:22)
E/flutter ( 2970): #4      new Future.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future.dart:176:37)       
E/flutter ( 2970): #5      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1120:38)
E/flutter ( 2970): #6      _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
E/flutter ( 2970): #7      _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:923:7)
E/flutter ( 2970): #8      _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:963:23)
E/flutter ( 2970): #9      _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1124:13)
E/flutter ( 2970): #10     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1021:19)
E/flutter ( 2970): #11     _CustomZone.bindCallback.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:947:23)
E/flutter ( 2970): #12     Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:21:15)
E/flutter ( 2970): #13     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:382:19)        
E/flutter ( 2970): #14     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:416:5)     
E/flutter ( 2970): #15     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:172:12)
```

Comment: The server didn't like something and returned status code 500, which typically means "server error". If you have access to the server, check its logs to see what it didn't like. If you do not, experiment with something like Postman or curl until you are able to get a successful response, then adapt your code to match. If you can't figure out how to make the necessary changes, then update the question with the working postman/curl details.

Comment: @RichardHeap encountered same error , in postman i'm getting response on sending EMPTY FILE. but getting the error in app on sending Empty string . any solutions or walkarounds?

Answer (score 0):

try wrap your file with this method

```
FormData formData = new FormData.fromMap({
          'name': image_name,
          'path': add_path + _uniq[0],
          'uuid': _uuid,
          'content_type': add_file + image_type,
          'file': await MultipartFile.fromFile('your file path', 'your file name with extention'),
          'record': null
});
```

Comment: I get error Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>'

Comment: convert `FormData formData` to `var formData`